# Swift – Balloons.playground – cannot add "textures" to the timeline

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, swift-playground

I'm playing around with the "Balloons.playground" tutorial, and when I try to add textures to the timeline by clicking the circle next to the line of code

```
let textures: [SKTexture] = images.map { SKTexture(imageNamed: "balloon-\($0)") }
```

I simply see "Unknown Error" repeated 13 times. What's going on?

Comment: are you sure you have the image assets? Have you imported SpriteKit?

Comment: Yes to both. The scene runs as it should. Just loaded up a fresh copy, same issue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Something has broken in Playgrounds since this post (Xcode 6 beta 4 was the most recent post when this was released.)

I tried a few alternatives, all of which failed similarly. I think viewing `SKTexture`s in playgrounds may simply be broken.

Here are a few of my attempts.

Switching to `for` loops (in case it was a `map` problem):

```
var textures : [SKTexture] = []
for imageName in images {
    let texture = SKTexture(imageNamed: "balloon-\(imageName)")!
    textures.append(texture)
}
```

Initializing just one:

```
let funTexture = SKTexture(imageNamed: "balloon-star-gold")
```

Trying a different initializer:

```
import Cocoa

[…]

let goldImage = NSImage(named: "balloon-star-gold")!
let goldTexture = SKTexture(image: goldImage)
```

None of these worked - all resulted in similar unclear errors.

Comment: Hi, Aaron, any chance you got this fixed since this post? I am (still) having similar issues. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I can't seem to create a texture from vectorNoiseWithSmoothness either.